# styled-components randomly generated class names causing snapshot differences

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using the `styled-components` library in my React app. This library generates class names for components through some hash function. This will frequently cause snapshot issues such as:

```
expected: <div class="some-div fHCbgz">
actual: <div class="some-div fc0Irp">
```

Sometimes, the class names will even change seemingly unexpectedly, perhaps in part because this is a large, complex, enterprise application. That being said, we ideally want to limit unnecessary snapshot updates in pull requests. What do we have to do to control the hash being generated, or otherwise limit changes in this hash value?

Comment: Found a couple issues in github in a quick search:
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/907
or
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1727

Comment: @DrewReese Honestly, this should be the answer.